# Laravel - No guarda imagen con Storage::

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de guardar una imagen usando el `Storage` de **Laravel**

```
Storage::disk('avatars')->put($avatarName, $request->file('avatar'))
$avatarName = avatar'.time().'.'.$request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

el problema es que no lo guarda como imagen solo aparece un texto:

```
/private/var/folders/d0/z0y__8kx4yzb3xp4f58f1rlh0000gn/T/phpTNwcQb
```

Alguien sabe porque no esta guardando la imagen correctamente, el nombre y la extensión la coloca de forma correcta, pero al parecer no guarda la imagen como tal.

Answer (score 0):

Para el almacenamiento de archivos en laravel puedes utilizar el método "store" que pertenece a la clase Request, te muestro el siguiente ejemplo, con una carga normal y uno con el renombre del archivo (código comentado):

```
    <?php 

     class HelloController extends Controller { 

         public function store(Request $request)
            if($request->hasFile('avatar')){ //validamos si existe algún archivo en el "Request"
             #Almacenando la imagen, store indicando la ruta
             $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('public/avatar'); 

             #ya que si quieres renombrar utiliza esto
             //$path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
                       //'public/avatar', "custom_name"
                     //);   
        } else {
        //To Do: Mensaje de advertencia
        }


}
```

Por otra parte te recomiendo que declares primero la variable con el nombre de la imagen y después de ello usar la variable en el metodo "Storage"
Espero sea de ayuda, saludos!